# Loading Icon While Images Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, load

How would I program a loading icon or graphic that appears while images on a page load. An example would be http://landerapp.com/?

My goal is to prevent the user from seeing this images on screen until they are ready to animate (see the problem at http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin with a visible loading image that is fixed in the exact middle of the screen. Then, when the page is fully loaded, we'll add a `"page_loaded"` class on the `<body>` which:

[1] begins the fade out of the loading image

[2] begins the fade in and translation of offscreen images to the screen

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.classList.add("page_loaded");
}
```

```css
.loader {     
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s opacity;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.right,
.left {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50em);  
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50em);  
}

.page_loaded .loader {
  opacity: 0;
}

.page_loaded .right,
.page_loaded .left {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<img class="loader" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/82092/screenshots/1073359/spinner.gif" alt="" />

<img src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg" alt="" class="right" />

<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTS704tVMgbKCry10AhT09VE8wBY5S9v-PWxTBOa7o52JU0TsjH" alt="" class="left" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Vanilla` or `jQuery` I'd suggest you to use [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/v3/) which is meant to achieve exactly what you want.

I'd go with something like this:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.img-container img').imagesLoaded().done(function(){
    console.log('images loaded');
    $('.img-container .loader').remove();
    $('.img-container img.hide').removeClass('hide');
  }).fail(function(){
    console.log('FAILED TO LOAD IMAGES');  
  });
});
```

```css
.img-responsive {
    max-width : 100%;  
  }
  
  .hide {
    display : none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.2.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="loader">
    Loading image....  
  </div>
  <img src="http://mascotafiel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/perros-Husky-Siberiano_opt-compressor-1.jpg" alt="PrettyCoolImage" class="img-responsive hide">
</div>
```